# How to change the "/portfolio" slug from Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site has a portfolio page by itself, and the link is www.example.com/portfolio. I tried to find the specific page (with this url), but i couldn't find. So my purpose is to create a portfolio page, on my wordpress site and have the specific url "www.example.com/portfolio". 
That where i did, to create a portfolio page, was to create a page and change the slug to "www.example.com/portfolio", but when i hit this url, show me the portfolio page, that has the site by itself and not my page.
So my question is, can i change the name of the existing url "/portfolio" and if yes, how (can i change it from my wordpress files), to appear the page i created and not existing page has the site by itself?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please share which plugins/themes you are using, that provide the `/portfolio` URL?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved the problem with permalink manager plugin. Changed the url of my page and solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Amin panel, go to pages... search for the page portfolio... there is no physical presence like portfolio.php... hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved the problem with permalink manager plugin. Changed the url of my page and the url page changed with "/portfolio"!

Answer (score 0):

Your WordPress page slugs aren't configured from within the codebase; instead if you go to the relevant page whilst in the admin dashboard, on the right hand side will be some config options - here is where you're able to change the slug.

[image: See Image]

How to change your slugs using permalinks [WordPress Docs](https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-permalinks-screen/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I solved the problem with permalink manager plugin. Changed the url of my page and the url page changed with "/portfolio"!

Answer (score 0):

It means you have a custom post type "portfolio". You need to unregister it. Put this code in the functions.php file of your active theme and then create a new page with a "portfolio" name(title).

```
if( !function_exists( 'cus_unregister_post_type' ) ) {
    function cus_unregister_post_type(){
        unregister_post_type( 'portfolio' );
    }
}
add_action('init','cus_unregister_post_type');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried your answer, but didn't helped me! So, I solved the problem with permalink manager plugin. Changed the url of my page and the url page changed with "/portfolio"!

Answer (score 0):

You just use this plugin and this plugin will help you.
Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: Thank you for your help! I used the permalink manager plugin and solved my problem!